# What are the semantics of `git reset stash`?

Tags: git

Today, I accidentally typed the command `git reset stash` and it did some very strange things to my recent history. It looks like at minimal, it removed the most recent commit, and added two other commits, one for the index and one for the stash itself.

I looked around `man git-reset` but did not find this behavior described there.

What is the intended semantic of this command, and is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stash` is recognized by git as a reference to the commit that contains the most recent stash - try `git rev-parse stash` or `cat .git/refs/stash`, which will print a commit SHA.

So `git reset stash` simply had the same effect as any `git reset <branch/tag/commit>`: it reset your current branch to point to the commit you indicated, and leaves any differences between the original and new commit as pending changes. (And stashes are made up of two commits, which as you say contain the index and the workdir changes.)

Comment: Totally did not realize stashes were also secretly commits!
Bonus learnings for the day, thanks!

Comment: Note that the stash commit (the one to which the name `stash` refers) is technically a merge commit, in that it has two parents, but it doesn't work like a regular merge commit and other parts of Git will show it oddly. It's not a good idea to leave the branch name pointing there. :-)

Comment: Good point from @torek: please reset back to your original commit ASAP ;-)